# microservice java classes - docker

Tags: docker, microservices

I have a maven project that includes multiple java packages that each implement a set of interfaces. I use the functions that I defined in the interfaces in my java applications.

I want to change the architecture of my project to a microservice architecture such that each subsystem can be executed in a container and each application that uses the interfaces should also be executed in a container.

Is that possible to containerize a class which implements an interface (not a class with a main function)? Would you please provide me an example of that? Whatever I found in the web is just a simple java application that can be executed in a container.

Comment: Closest thing I can think of is https://spring.io/blog/2017/07/05/introducing-spring-cloud-function , perhaps with project riff

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look

Comment: Not sure I understand the implementation. So you want to call functions from other functions that live inside a separate Docker container?

Comment: Yes. Suppose I have an application running inside a container and it needs to create an instance of a class which implements an interface and it should be running in another container.

Comment: A class that implements a functionality and it can be used in java applications

Comment: I don't think this is possible but curious why you would want such a use case? The only interface as far as I'm aware is via the network which means you can make a network request from one container to another. What would effectively be wrong with this approach?

Comment: I think I found the answer. It looks like WSO2 framework can be used for implementing of  what I need. In the examples that they provided in their website, each class (it can be anything) can be implemented as a service. I guess it should be possible to run them in different containers.

Comment: Oh... you're asking about serverless. That has nothing that quite deals with containers in that case or at least it would be an abstraction where you don't even see the existence of the containers. Its similar to attaching a handler to serve a request in AWS Lambda for instance: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-programming-model-handler-types.html.